# Assembly Language implementation of C instruction

Tags: assembly, mips

I am trying to translate `A[2*i]=A[2*k+j];` into assembly language. Array 'A' of ints (four bytes) starts at address `Astart` (32 bit) and `i, j, k` are stored in `$s0, $s1, $s3`.

So if I am understanding the problem correctly, I need to set the address and value of the `[2*k+j]` element to the `[2*i]` element? My confusion is modifying the addresses. This is what I have:

```
add $t0, $s0, $s0       #2*i
add $t1, $s3, $s3       #2*k
add $t2, $t1, $s3       #2*k+j
sw $t2, Astart
sw $t0 4(Astart)
```

Is this correct?

Comment: I am an x86 assembly programmer. I don't know MIPS. But looking at its index addressing mode might help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two steps necessary here, first to load from `A[2*k+j]` and second to store at `A[2*i]`.

You have already calculated `2*i` and `2*k+j`, but you have forgotten to multiply by 4 (because the offset of each element of a 32 bit integer is 4 bytes).

The corrected code might look like:

```
add $t0, $s0, $s0       #2*i
add $t1, $s3, $s3       #2*k
add $t2, $t1, $s3       #2*k+j

sll $t1 $t1 2
sll $t2 $t2 2

la $t0 Astart
add $t3 $t0 $t1 #Address of A[2*k]
add $t4 $t0 $t2 #Address of A[2*k+j]

lw $t0 0($t3)
sw $t0 0($t4)
```

Comment: Can you explain why $t1 and $t2 are multiplied by 4? I'm not sure what you mean by the offset

Comment: @spearman008 In your question you define array 'A' as an array of ints (each int being 4 bytes).  If you do not multiply by 4, you are only accessing data by an offset of 1 byte and you need to go 4 bytes to get the next element (since each element is defined as being 4 bytes).